# Error installing Social Engine

Tags: .htaccess, failed-installation, socialengine

I've got a problem trying to install Social Engine. Upload all files, set directory permissions, but when I enter my domain, I get a:

```
Not Found

The requested URL /install/install was not found on this server.
```

It's something related to the .htaccess files in root and install directory, 'cause removing them I do begin the installation process BUT with long URLs, this way:

/install/index.php/install

And that's something that would end up with all long URLS, instead of short ones that google use to index, for example. My ISP has safe_mode OFF, and mod_rewrite ON, so I'm just kinda lost...

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess :

```
# $Id: .htaccess 7539 2010-10-04 04:41:38Z john $

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymLinks
  RewriteEngine On

  # Get rid of index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /index\.php
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=2 [L,QSA]

  # Rewrite all directory-looking urls
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*) index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

  # Try to route missing files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} public\/ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(jpg|gif|png|ico|flv|htm|html|php|css|js)$
  RewriteRule . - [L]

  # If the file doesn't exist, rewrite to index
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?rewrite=1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>

# sends requests /index.php/path/to/module/ to "index.php"
# AcceptPathInfo On

# @todo This may not be effective in some cases
FileETag Size
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue running SocialEngine on Vagrant (using https://box.scotch.io/) and fixed it by clearing the `.htaccess` file under `/install/`.